# Angular Datatable is not loading on first Load

Tags: angular2-forms, angular-datatables

Here im using DataTable with Angular2 Here DataTable is working wen i refresh the page.But its not loading on 1st Run

```
<table datatable class="row-border hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Auction ID</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

        <tr *ngFor="let value of auction">
          <td>{{value.name}}</td>
      <tbody>
    </table>
```

At The same time i used normal DataTable(Without *ngFor="") its working fine without any issue

```
<table datatable class="row-border hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Auction ID</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>

            <tr>
              <td>John</td>
          <tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: Which plugin you are using? could you so that link?. Shall i tell another data table for you?

Comment: https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/getting-started